# How do I use a self referential struct definition (in C)?

Tags: c

Here is my situation. I have a hash-table and a node as my structures. The nodes have pointers to other nodes (a linked-list), and the hash-table is an array of nodes. I define the two structures as:

```
typedef struct node{
    char* hashStr;
    struct node* nextNode;
}node;

typedef struct hashTable{
   int emptyNodes[16];
   node* pods[16];
}hashTable;
```

I have defined the maximum amount of nodes in a linked-list as 32. Whenever I add a node to the linked-list, I check if  the linked-list is of length 32. If the length is 32, and I want to add another node, I want to delete the first node in the linked-list, and add the new node to the back, like a FIFO queue.

My issue is in deleting the first node. Instead of deleting the first node, I think the most reasonable thing is to have the node pointer in the hashTable (that is at some key (since it is an array of node pointers)), simply point to the next node which is referred to as `nextNode` in the `node struct`. I can't do this though because `nextNode` is NOT a `struct`.

I tried this:

```
(*addr).pods[key] = (*addr).pods[key].nextNode;
```

I get the error:

```
error: request for member 'nextNode' in something not a structure or union
```

I understand the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I found this on stackoverflow, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my work (if I even can):

[Why do I get "request for member in something not a struct or union" from this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994957/why-do-i-get-request-for-member-in-something-not-a-struct-or-union-from-this-c)

Comment: `pods[key]` is a pointer. You need to use `pods[key]->nextNode`.

Comment: You rather get the error because the item you are using is _not_ a struct. Read the compiler error carefully. Proper code should be `addr->pods[key] = addr->pods[key]->nextNode;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(*addr).pods[key] = (*addr).pods[key]->nextNode;
```

The `pods` is an array of pointers. Once you have the pointer, you need to dereference it to access the underlying object.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
(*addr).pods[key].nextNode;
```

to this:

```
(*addr).pods[key]->nextNode;
```

since `pods[key]` is of type `node*`, i.e. a *pointer* to a `node`.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
node* pods[16];
```

`pods[key]` is of `node*` type. While accessing `nextNode` using `pods[key]` use arrow `->` operator. For e.g

```
(*addr).pods[key]->nextNode
```

Comment: True @alk lot of mistakes happens today itself. Thanks for correcting.